# Elements in the table that are part of section (i.e: A) should be placed at the bottom of the table

Tags: javascript

I have a set of elements. Some of these are part of section A, others of section B and still others of section C. There is a special column that defines this Section.

The elements in the table that are part of section A must be placed at the bottom of the table.

To be able to put the elements at the bottom of the table I know that you have to use the command:

`var row = table.insertRow(-1);`

Since my table is dynamic, how can I set what I want?

```js
Items.forEach(function (item) {               
                    let child = document.createElement("tr");
                    child.innerHTML = `
                    <td>${item.id}</td>
                    <td>${item.title}</td>
                    <td>${item.image}</td> 
                    <td>${item.section}</td>
                    <td>${item.date}</td>`;
                    table.appendChild(child);
                })
```

```html
    <table id="my-table" width="90%">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Section</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

**Example to understand**

```js
let itemarr = [{
  id: 1,
  title: "image 1",
  image: "url 1",
  section: "Film",
  date: "date 1",
}, {
  id: 2,
  title: "image 2",
  image: "url 2",
  section: "Video",
  date: "date 2",
},
{
  id: 3,
  title: "image 3",
  image: "url 2",
  section: "Film",
  date: "date 2",
},
{
  id: 4,
  title: "image 4",
  image: "url 2",
  section: "Video",
  date: "date 2",
}]
itemarr.forEach(function(item) {
  let child = document.querySelector('table').insertRow(-1)
  child.innerHTML = `
                    <td>${item.id}</td>
                    <td>${item.title}</td>
                    <td>${item.image}</td> 
                    <td>${item.section}</td>
                    <td>${item.date}</td>`

})
```

```html
<table id="my-table" width="90%">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Section</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track by using `insertRow(-1)`.

Try this one will work, a small notice that `Items` is currently `undefined` but I believe you define it

```js
let itemarr = [{
  id: 1,
  title: "image 1",
  image: "url 1",
  section: "section 1",
  date: "date 1",
}, {
  id: 2,
  title: "image 2",
  image: "url 2",
  section: "section 2",
  date: "date 2",
}]
itemarr.forEach(function(item) {
  let child = document.querySelector('table').insertRow(-1)
  child.innerHTML = `
                    <td>${item.id}</td>
                    <td>${item.title}</td>
                    <td>${item.image}</td> 
                    <td>${item.section}</td>
                    <td>${item.date}</td>`

})
```

```css
table {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<table id="my-table" width="90%">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Section</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>title</td>
    <td>image</td>
    <td>section</td>
    <td>date</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: But I just want to put the elements that belong to a certain section at the bottom of the table. Specifically, I want to put at the bottom of the table only those that belong to the "Movies" section. I don't get what I want as you say

Comment: Could you give a complete example by placing an array as you like and inserting in the photo only the elements that belong to the "Movie" section?

Comment: @s_o_p_h_i_a, I am confused what is the movie section? I understand that the movie section is a table. Is it a `tr` or table? Sure I will provide you an example

Comment: @s_o_p_h_i_a, update the code now, is the `put the elements that belong to a certain section at the bottom of the table` certain section means  a`th` tag in `tr`?

Comment: In the sense that I have various sections in the Section column: ie Movies, Videos, Youtube Videos. I have to put at the bottom of the table only the elements that belong to the "Movies" section.
For example, where you put Section1 and Section2, suppose it says instead of Section1 Movie, instead of Section2 Video, Section3 is VideoYoutube, Section4 is Movie. I want "Movie" to be placed at the bottom of the table. Obviously I have more elements.

Comment: I hope I have been clear

Comment: @s_o_p_h_i_a, OK, based on my understanding, section is your own division to the rows. I think the code should work and you want `movie` to placed at the end, just use the code above at the end of script will work

Comment: can you show me exactly the code in full? Yes, right

Comment: @s_o_p_h_i_a, check the update again. It is almost every thing I could do to show the full code(I don't have full code). You could see as long as you put it in bottom of the script, it works

Comment: Excuse me one thing, which is not clear to me. Why are there two times <tr> ??

Comment: I'll try and let you know

Comment: @s_o_p_h_i_a, never mind that, just want to show you the code insert rows at the end, the second `tr` is just another row

Comment: I tried. If I try to insert a line with Section Video this is also put at the bottom of the table. It is in the middle of the movies. I, on the other hand, would like only the films to be found below. Obviously the contents of the table are updated, they do not remain fixed

Comment: @s_o_p_h_i_a, the problem caused this is because you  use insertRow(-1) for  inserting rows you want to put it in middle and you use it at the end. I don't think insertRow has option for middle (only top/bottom), so at this point, be careful with the sequence

Comment: If you see the example in my updated answer, Video is on the first line, while I want it to be found below along with the others (because it is part of Film)

Comment: and if eventually a function was created to manage this thing in the table? I don't know why I never did. I ask for help with this

Comment: @s_o_p_h_i_a, well, then it comes to the problem we need to filter the data based on the type. To be honest, it is much better for me and others who want to help if you point out this at the begining. Do you mind posting another problem about filtering data problem and I am glad to answering (tell me if you want)\ because the answer now is too long and mainly about table structure?:)

Comment: Certain. Asked a new question, but could you please answer soon? I am stuck on this

Comment: @s_o_p_h_i_a, absolutely, just don't forgot to tell me once you do that! (comment here:)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71042086/how-to-filter-in-the-table-so-that-they-end-up-at-the-bottom-of-the-table-the Done, I hope you help me because I'm desperate

Comment: @s_o_p_h_i_a, better if you post the example (you need to understand) for other people there!

Comment: Done, I put it on

Comment: I'm waiting for your answer. I know well that you will help me

Comment: @s_o_p_h_i_a, encounter a problem, post an answer just now!